# Comparing numbers of type string

Tags: javascript

I'm implementing a sort function and came across the following:

```
'49' > '5' // false
'49' > '4' // true

new String(49).localeCompare('4') // 1
new String(49).localeCompare('5') // -1
```

Expected behaviour is obviously that 49 > 4 or 5 should be true. Is there any way to solve this without  converting the strings to numbers?

Comment: Are you asking this out of curiosity or did you face any issue converting to numbers, as in a performance hit?

Comment: You could do something funny with Function constructor

Comment: @aduch You can always do something funny with the function constructor ;). But I prefer not to evaluate stuff

Comment: @Johan: String comparison can be altered by wrapping the string into objects and defining your valueOf operators. Way too much work, but nevertheless possible. Just telling, probably you know it, using a + in front of the string converts it to a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is actually expected behavior when comparing strings, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7087811/string-comparison-in-javascript). The easiest thing for this situation would be to convert the values to numbers for comparison if you want to compare them as numbers.

Thinking outside the box a little, you could first compare the length of the strings before using the `>` operator.  If they are numeric strings, the longer string would have a higher value (assuming you don't have numbers like '0024').  If they are equal in length, the `>` operator would then work as you expect.

Comment: So it's because `'4'.charCodeAt() < '5'.charCodeAt()`?