# If Current Date > Today not working Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a javascript file i'm trying to use and the dates are not working out. Sorry if this a duplicate question. FYI - I'm not well versed in JS yet so please be patient!

To get current date I did this

```
var today = new Date()
var month = today.getMonth()+1;
var day = today.getDate();
var year = today.getFullYear();
var currentdate = month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
```

Now when I run this if statement it is telling me `currentdate > week3` is true. What am I missing here?

```
var week3 = "04/17/2016";
var nl = "<br>";
if(currentdate > week3) {
document.write(week3.strike() + " " + week3info.strike() + nl); }
else {
document.write(week3 + week3info + nl); }
```

Comment: week3 and currentdate are both strings so not comparable (it is but not the way you think). You should compare the timestamp from the date object eg. `if( new Date().getTime() > new Date( week3 ).getTime() ) { ... }`

Comment: @synthet1c Worked! Thanks for the help. Makes sense about the string issue. Thank again, big help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`currentdate` and `week3` are both strings, and are compared using a ["fancy alphabetical order"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7087831/3960399) when using `>` and `<`.

As stated in one of the comments, use Dates instead of strings for the type of comparison that you want.

```
if(new Date() > new Date(week3)) { ... }
```

See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript) for more information if you're interested.