# How does string comparison work in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

What the algorithm work behind string comparison in javascript, for example

```
'bc' > 'ac' = true/false ?
'ac' > 'bc' = true/false ?
```

Comment: Strings are compared alphabetically. `b` is greater than `a` etc.

Comment: what about  é and e ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is one string greater than the other when comparing strings in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7087811/why-is-one-string-greater-than-the-other-when-comparing-strings-in-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is calculated using [The Abstract Relational Comparison Algorithm](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.8.5) in ECMA-5. The relevant part is quoted below.

```
4. Else, both px and py are Strings
    a) If py is a prefix of px, return false. (A String value p is a prefix 
       of String value q if q can be the result of concatenating p and some
       other String r. Note that any String is a prefix of itself, because 
       r may be the empty String.)
    b) If px is a prefix of py, return true.
    c) Let k be the smallest nonnegative integer such that the character 
       at position k within px is different from the character at position 
       k within py. (There must be such a k, for neither String is a prefix 
       of the other.)
    d) Let m be the integer that is the code unit value for the character 
       at position k within px.
    e) Let n be the integer that is the code unit value for the character 
       at position k within py.
    f) If m < n, return true. Otherwise, return false.
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript compares strings by the order of [Unicode codepoints](https://www.ssec.wisc.edu/%7Etomw/java/unicode.html#x0000) and lexicographically compares UTF-16 code units.

From your question:

```js
'bc' > 'ac' // Because 'b' comes after 'a'.
```

Answer (score 1):

Not only in javascript , In simple, all string comparison algorithm will follow the **lexicographical order or dictionary order**, which means it will check each character by character, if some mismatches, you can decide the result

```
True: 
ant < any
aaa < aab 
aab < b 
b < baa
```

Answer (score 0):

Strings are compared character by character, so the very first letter is the most significant, hence

```
'bc' > 'ac' = true/false ? => true
'ac' > 'bc' = true/false ? => false
```

if the first letter will be equal then, second will be compared and so on, till one of them will be greater or less or equal.