# java script string comparison

Tags: javascript, string, if-statement, comparison

I took a JS course on a website , and in one of the lessons there was a piece Of code that did not make sense to me :

[image]

the code is in the picture , why str1 is less then str2 ?

Comment: Can you include text of `javascript` at Question?

Comment: Because `a` comes before `b`.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabetical_order , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order

Comment: the strings are compared in character by character mode and every character has its code (Unicode) representation. Finally, it is the charatcters' codes in both strings that get compared.

Comment: `"a".codePointAt(0)  => 97` , `"b".codePointAt(0) => 98`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does string comparison work in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38498110/218196)

Answer (score 2):

Strings are compared based on standard lexicographical ordering, using Unicode values. That means "a" < "b" and "c" > "b"

> Two strings are strictly equal when they have the same sequence of
>   characters, same length, and same characters in corresponding
>   positions. [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)

```js
var str1 = "aardvark";
var str2="beluga";
console.log(str1 < str2);//true
console.log(str1.length < str2.length);//false
```

Answer (score 0):

This compares each character from 0-index, for example `"a"<"b"` thi is `true`. If there are equal, it compares next index, and next, ...
`"aad">"aac"`, because, twice `"a"="a"` and then `"d">"c"`

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript in this case will compare the strings lexographically character by character, where the letter 'a' is lower than the letter 'b' and so on. It works for numbers too, and the uppercase alphabet is considerd higher than the lowercase alphabet.

So, in your example, `'a' < 'b'` and therefore the statement is true.