# Deterministic string compare in JS/TS?

Tags: javascript, typescript, string-comparison

I am looking for a deterministic way of sorting a list of strings.

Sorting a string of course often leads to the suggestion to use [String.localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare). But the order must be deterministic, unrelated to the computer where it is running on.

The hardcore solution I came up with is hashing each string and compare these instead with a locale option `en`. Is there an easier solution?

The strings can be English, German, Chinese, Japanese, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oddly, what fits your requirements is...the default `sort`:

```
theStrings.sort();
```

That sorts according to the UTF-16 code units in the strings, which doesn't vary by computer/locale/whatever. It treats the strings as (effectively) a series of 16-bit numbers (Unicode code units, to be precise).

From [the specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.sort):

> If *comparefn* is not undefined, it should be a function that accepts two arguments *x* and *y* and returns a negative Number if *x* `<` *y*, a positive Number if *x* `>` *y*, or a zero otherwise.

And the `<` and `>` operators are defined by the abstract [IsLessThan](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-islessthan) operation in the specification, which compares by the code units in the string.

Comment: Lol! I thought it implies a `localeCompare`. On the other hand, I have actually a `Map` object where I need to sort the keys. Means I use the actual key

`new Map(Array.from(myMap.entries()).sort((a, b) => ???))`

Comment: @HelloWorld - It was perfectly reasonable (IMHO) to assume the default sort, which is defined in string terms, would use `localeCompare`. It doesn't, but it was a completely reasonable assumption. :-D

Comment: Thanks! I think your post edit filled the last gap. I can rely on `<` and `>`

Answer (score 1):

Two solutions:

- use a specific locale, not the current one like [`localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare). JS supports this through the [`Intl.Collator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/Collator):

  ```
  arr.sort(new Intl.Collator('en').compare)
  ```

  Choose whatever language you need.
- use the [standard lexicographic comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38498110/1048572) that the builtin `<`/`>` operators for strings supply:

  ```
  arr.sort((a, b) => +(a>b)||-(b>a))
  arr.sort()
  ```

Comment: That is also very helpful, thank you, especially the latter