# new Date() on javascript gives different result when comparing the results

Tags: javascript

code:

```
var userDate = "7/9/2016"
    var d = new Date(userDate);
    var daTe = d.toLocaleString();

 var today = "7/27/2016"
    var md = new Date(today);
    var td = md.toLocaleString();

    if (daTe > td) {
        alert("YES!")
    }
```

how come the `userDate` is greater than `today`? when I use 7/2/2016 to 7/9/2016
on `userDate` as value? Please explain.

Comment: That's because you are comparing two strings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) returns a string, so you're comparing two strings, not two dates. If you want to compare the dates, you can compare either the date objects themselves, or their timestamps.

Both of these will return `false`:

```javascript
d > md
```

```javascript
d.getTime() > md.getTime()
```

Comment: Just adding this link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7087811/why-is-one-string-greater-than-the-other-when-comparing-strings-in-javascript) for an overview if you compare strings as mentioned within the question. Quote: "strings are compared lexicographically"