# Jquery comparison not working properly

Tags: jquery

```
received = parseFloat($('input[name=amount_received]').val()).toFixed(2);
total_amount= parseFloat($('input[name=total_bill]').val()).toFixed(2);
```

wherein the inputted value for received is 99 and 3930.85 for total amount

```
if(received >= total_amount) {

console.log("full");

} else {

console.log("partial");

}
```

it always says full,

can someone please help and explain why

Answer (score -2, accepted):

When you performed the toFixed function, it converted the value to a string. Therefore, string "99" is always greater than string "3930.85".

What you could've done to fix that is:

```
received = parseFloat($('input[name=amount_received]').val().toFixed(2));
total_amount= parseFloat($('input[name=total_bill]').val().toFixed(2));
```

The code above does the conversion after the toFixed function.

Comment: What is the benefit of using `toFixed`, only to `parseInt` it back to an integer?

Comment: parseFloat and parseInt are different.

Comment: `toFixed()` is broken and should not be used for rounding.

Answer (score 0):

Because [`toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) returns a string, you're comparing strings instead of numbers. In a string-based comparison, `99` will come after `3930.85`, and the greater-than-or-equal comparison will evaluate to true.

Getting rid of the call to `toFixed()` will solve it.

```js
received = parseFloat($('input[name=amount_received]').val());
total_amount = parseFloat($('input[name=total_bill]').val());

if (received >= total_amount) {
  console.log("full");

} else {
  console.log("partial");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input name="amount_received" value="99" />
<input name="total_bill" value="3930.85" />
```

As a side note, using `toFixed()` is unreliable when it comes to rounding. In both current Chrome and Firefox, calling `toFixed()` yields the following inconsistent results:

```
35.655.toFixed(2) // Yields "36.66" (correct)
35.855.toFixed(2) // Yields "35.85" (wrong, should be "35.86")
```

See also the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10015027/javascript-tofixed-not-rounding) and refer to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round#Decimal_rounding) for a reliable rounding method.

Comment: And for you too sir

Answer (score -1):

From the [`.toFixed()` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed).

> **Return value**
>   A string representing the given number using fixed-point notation.

When you then do a comparison of one string `>=` the other its giving you a lexicologically ordered comparison (ie. `"9" > "3"` so `"99.00" > "3930.85"`). Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7087831/648350), for more details about the quirks of String based comparison.

Hold off on using `.toFixed()` until you've completed any arithmetic on your numbers, then use it for display.

**JS**

```
received = parseFloat($('input[name=amount_received]').val());
total_amount = parseFloat($('input[name=total_bill]').val());
```

Comment: No less than two downvotes for a correct answer. I'll offset the balance for you +1