# Accept date from user within particular range

Tags: javascript

I have a form through which I want to accept date only within give date range. But, which ever date I am fetching, it is returning false and showing incorrect range.
Following are the codes related-

register.html-

```
<div class="form-group row">
      <label for="date" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label class='control-label' ">Date of Birth</label>
      <div class="col-sm-5">
      <input type="date" max="2010-12-31" min="1990-01-01"  id="dob" placeholder="Date of birth"> 
      </div>
    </div>
```

controller.js-

```
var dobInput = document.forms["myform"]["dob"].value;
    var maxdate = new Date("2010-12-31");
    var mindate= new Date("1990-01-01");
    if(maxdate>dobInput && dobInput>mindate)
    {
        alert("correct range");
    }
    else{
        alert("Input out of range");
return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Value you're getting is returned as a string, however you're attempting to evaluate this against Date type variables - this will not work as a string to string evaluation will be done [lexicographically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7087811/why-is-one-string-greater-than-the-other-when-comparing-strings-in-javascript).

You should instead convert the value to a date first:

```
var inputDate = new Date(dobInput);
if(maxdate>inputDate && inputDate >mindate){
   ...
```

Comment: Glad I could help! It would make sense if an input of type "date" returned a date object however the type merely allows the browser to change it's native rendering mechanism.

Comment: Yeah..I got it now.

Answer (score 0):

Your input is a string. so convert to Date first and check with getTime method. Correct code is as below..

```
var dobInput = document.forms["myform"]["dob"].value;
var maxdate = new Date("2010-12-31");
var mindate= new Date("1990-01-01");
var dateToChk = new Date(dobInput);
if(maxdate.getTime()>dobInput.getTime() && dobInput.getTime()>mindate.getTime())
{
    alert("correct range");
}
else{
    alert("Input out of range");
    return false;
}
```