# How to compare innerHTML (string comparison in JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, string, if-statement, comparison

I was working on filtering a table alphabetically and ran into a problem. I don't understand `x.innerHTML > y.innerHTML` concept in this code:

```
 table = document.getElementById('myTable');
 rows = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');
 x = rows[1].getElementsByTagName('td')[0];
 y = rows[2].getElementsByTagName('td')[0];
 //check if the two rows should switch place:
 console.log(x.innerHTML.length, y.innerHTML.length);
 console.log(x.innerHTML > y.innerHTML);
```

How does it work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is one string greater than the other when comparing strings in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7087811/why-is-one-string-greater-than-the-other-when-comparing-strings-in-javascript)

Comment: FYI, you don't need `getElementsByTagName` there. `table.rows[1].cells[0]` works just as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`innerHTML` returns a string, so you just compare two strings:

```
"albert" < "boby" // true
```

From [ECMAScript Language Specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/)

> The comparison of Strings uses a simple lexicographic ordering on sequences of code unit values. There is no attempt to use the more complex, semantically oriented definitions of character or string equality and collating order defined in the Unicode specification. Therefore String values that are canonically equal according to the Unicode standard could test as unequal. In effect this algorithm assumes that both Strings are already in normalised form. Also, note that for strings containing supplementary characters, lexicographic ordering on sequences of UTF-16 code unit values differs from that on sequences of code point values.

Answer (score 1):

`x.innerHTML` and `y.innerHTML` are *strings*, therefore if you want their value as a number, you need to surround them with `Number()` as follows:

```
Number(x.innerHTML)>Number(y.innerHTML)
```

Otherwise, you are comparing two strings with an inequality, which the computer takes a different way, as shown above in another answer.

Comment: Basically, in JS `"a" < "b" //true` but `"b" < "a" //false` because a comes before b in the alphabet