# undefined == undefined is true. But undefined >= undefined is false?

Tags: javascript, undefined

I just have more of a trivial question.

Why does `undefined == undefined` return `true`, but `undefined >= undefined` is `false`?

`undefined` is equal to `undefined`.

But it is not equal to or greater?

Comment: My guess is that both `undefined`s are coerced to `NaN` which is not equal to itself.

Comment: `undefined === undefined || undefined > undefined`  and `undefined >= undefined`, the OR in "greater than or equal to" is not the same as this OR `||`

Comment: @DeepakKamat what happens behind the scenes of `>=`? I think that's what this question is getting at

Comment: `undefined` isn't number and that is what happens. 

`10 >= "hello world"` returns false is simple to understand. So my guess is using comparison operator on Not a Number would always return false.

Comment: Yeah, I'd agree with Xufox. JavaScript probably tries to convert them to some comparable values, e.g. a number. But undefined converted to a number is NaN, which is neither equal to itself nor greater than itself.

Comment: I have the same thought with @Xufox. Because we all know the equal operator will try to convert the type before it actually compares the value. You can refer to the link here to see how type will be converted when performing equality comparison. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness
But for >= I have no idea though.

Comment: @trungk18 basically, it first tries to get either a string or a number if they are objects and from there on it will convert them to numbers if both of them aren't a string.

Comment: [wat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgPi4.png)

Comment: It's Javascript. Don't attempt to use logic.

Comment: [Obligatory wat lightning talk](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat)

Comment: Try `x = {valueOf(){ return NaN }}; console.log(x == x, x >= x)`. The `==` operator does not always do relational comparison.

Answer (score 46):

The [`>=` operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.8.4) is essentially the negation of the [`<` operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.8.1). And both invoke the [Abstract Relational Comparison Algorithm](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.8.5) which returns *undefined* for `undefined >= undefined` as defined in step 3 (a to c). Actually, you can also see that **the greater-than(-or-equal) and less-than(-or-equal) operators are only meant to work with either numbers or strings**.

Then in the 6. step of the specification of the `>=` operator, you can see why it returns *false*:

> If `r` is *true* or *undefined*, return *false*. Otherwise, return *true*.

Answer (score 8):

`undefined === undefined || undefined > undefined` and `undefined >= undefined`, the OR in "greater than or equal to" is not the same as this OR `||`.

As far as it is concerned the comparison operators like `>, <, >=` etc are meant for numbers and `undefined` isn't numbers, `undefined` is undefined.

What would you expect as a return value when `10 >= "Hello World"`? Of course a false, but again `10 >= "10"` returns `true` because `10 == "10"` is true and `10 === "10"` is false. The "10" can be converted into a number so we see the result that would have been returned in case of an actual number and not a string with numbers.

There is no strict equality operator version for `>=` as opposed to `!=` which is `!==`

Some really weird and confusing things happen when you try comparing `null`, `undefined`, `NaN` - This is something that the specification of JavaScript may be able to answer and since JavaScript is a very loosely typed language and the types are very flexible that is why one can compare `10` and `"10"` and still get results which you may have gotten only when you compared two integers in most of the other languages.

Answer (score 2):

Inequality operators (`<`, `>`, and so on) cannot be used to compare values that cannot be implicitly converted to numbers. This includes `undefined`. The reason behind what you're seeing is that, unlike other languages that throw an error if you try to do something like this anyway (i.e. `TypeError` in python), JS lets you do it. However, the result will always be false.

Comment: This doesn’t explain why `"foo" >= "bar"` is `true` and doesn’t include an explanation of how operators coerce their operands to a matching type.

Comment: @Xufox because JavaScript is a damned loosely typed language. It can convert strings that has numbers in strings and compare and that is it also has a "===" operator to do a strict comparison instead of simple converting strings to integers and floats.

Comment: Actually, when using inequalities, strings are compared [lexicographically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7087831/7662085).