# Compare two strings with the relational operator it gives true

Tags: javascript

When we use relational operator to compare two string in JavaScript.           "11"<"3" how and why it gives the true in the answer

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Which comes first in a dictionary: "Aaaaa" or "B"?

Comment: `"11" < "3"` is not the same as `11 < 3`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is one string greater than the other when comparing strings in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7087811/why-is-one-string-greater-than-the-other-when-comparing-strings-in-javascript)

Answer (score -1):

strings use alphabetical order based comparison