# Wrong way of defining form validators in Angular 5?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-validation

I'm using individual control validators in the forms of an Angular app and they work perfectly. Now, I wanted to add a validator for checking that the value of a control is less than other control's, and I read that I must apply the validator to the parent of the control (the FormGroup itself).

So, I did some tests that you can see in the following stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mts2gq

I'm sure that I have something wrong with the `sourcePortsValidator` and `destPortsValidator`, because they don't work as expected. For example, have a look at this screenshot:

[image]

And the console:

[image]

It says that `start` is 20, `end` is 120 and the comparison `start>end` is `true`. A little weird, isn't it? What would it be the right way of defining these validators?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer:

In your HTML, change the **type** of the *source port start* and *source port end* input boxes to `number`.

Long answer:

Inputs of `text` type return their value as `string` so `start > end` actually compares the port numbers as `string` (lexicographically). See [Why is one string greater than the other when comparing strings in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7087811/why-is-one-string-greater-than-the-other-when-comparing-strings-in-javascript).

Comment: Worked like a charm. What a silly thing it was! Thank you very much :)