# whats difference here with string and numbers in javascript arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures

I am merging two sorted arrays in JavaScript. When I call function with two arrays having numbers it works fine, but when I call that function with strings then it does not work. Why?

```js
function mergeSortedArrays(array1, array2) {
  const mergedArray = [];
  let array1Item = array1[0];
  let array2Item = array2[0];
  let i = 1;
  let j = 1;

  if (array1.length === 0) {
    return array2;
  }
  if (array2.length === 0) {
    return array1;
  }

  while (array1Item || array2Item) {
    if (array2Item === undefined || array1Item < array2Item) {
      mergedArray.push(array1Item);
      array1Item = array1[i];
      i++;
    } else {
      mergedArray.push(array2Item);
      array2Item = array2[j];
      j++;
    }
  }
  console.log(mergedArray);
}

//working?
mergeSortedArrays([0, 3, 4, 12, 222], [3, 4, 6, 30]);

// not working why?
mergeSortedArrays(["0", "3", "4", "12", "222"], ["3", "4", "6", "30"]);
```

Comment: Strings are compared lexically; `"222"` is smaller than `"3"`.

Comment: As @ChrisG said strings could not be compared like the numbers.

Comment: is it really necessary to downvote OP's question? For me, it seems ok, he have a real question, with real code, he only didn't know about the lexical comparassion

Comment: @CalvinNunes It's fine, because a minimum amount of research would've been enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the comments, strings in JS are compared lexically , so, "222" is smaller than "3".

A solution that I see that you can use, is this one: 

 After checking the arrays for nullity, then concat then into `mergedArray`, then use the JS function `sort()`, with the basic return of `value1 - value2`, that way it will sort the strings in the order you want, and also will work for numbers.

(Further read: [Why is one string greater than the other when comparing strings in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7087811/why-is-one-string-greater-than-the-other-when-comparing-strings-in-javascript))

```js
function mergeSortedArrays(array1, array2) {
  let mergedArray = [];

  if (array1.length === 0) {
    return array2;
  }
  if (array2.length === 0) {
    return array1;
  }

  mergedArray = array1.concat(array2)
  mergedArray.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a - b
  })
  console.log(mergedArray);
  return mergedArray;
}


mergeSortedArrays([0, 3, 4, 12, 222], [3, 4, 6, 30]);
mergeSortedArrays(["0", "3", "4", "12", "222"], ["3", "4", "6", "30"]);
```

BUT, be knowing that this solution will only work as expected if the strings are representations of numbers (`"1", "2",...`), if it is something like `"aa", "abc", "b"` it probably won't work well and another solution may be needed. (something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51169/8732818)

Answer (score 0):

Sort for string works differently than numbers. Its based on the ASCII table values. For example "99" > "100000" return should return true

Comment: JavaScript uses Unicode, not ASCII. But you knew that, right? `console.log("")`